# redirect reference of child objects

Tags: javascript

I have a main javascript object (this array I put into json_encode function in php script on server side):

```
array(
'priceManager' => array(
    'array' => array(
        'log' => array(
            'options' => array(
                'path' => 'local'
            )
        ),

        'settings' => array(
            'options' => array(
                'path' => 'local'
            )
        ),

        'articles' => array(
            'options' => array(
                'path' => 'global',
                'lifetime' => '0:00:15'
            )
        ),

        'currencies' => array(
            'options' => array(
                'path' => 'global',
                'lifetime' => '0:00:15'
            )
        )
    ),

    'item' => array(
        'dbConnect' => array(
            'options' => array(
                'hostName' => '***',
                'userName' => '***',
                'password' => '***',
                'databaseName' => '***'
            )
        ),

        'getPrice' => array(
            'options' => array(
                'curr' => 'RUB',
                'method' => 'floor',
                'accuracy' => 5,
                'ratio' => array(
                    'all' => 1.1,
                    '001' => 1.2,
                    '0012' => 1.5
                )
            )
        ),

        'getExchange' => array(
            'options' => array(
                'method' => 'floor',
                'accuracy' => 5
            )
        ),

        'getRow' => array(
            'options' => array(
                'template' => array(
                    array('function' => 'getName'), '!', array('function' => 'getPrice', 'params' => 'EUR'), '!', array('function' => 'getCurrency')
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
);
```

and after document has been loaded, I split it into several smaller objects like this (by 'options' key):

```
            'options' => array(
                'path' => 'local'
            )

            'options' => array(
                'path' => 'local'
            )

            'options' => array(
                'path' => 'global',
                'lifetime' => '0:00:15'
            )

            'options' => array(
                'path' => 'global',
                'lifetime' => '0:00:15'
            )

            'options' => array(
                'hostName' => '***',
                'userName' => '***',
                'password' => '***',
                'databaseName' => '***'
            )

            'options' => array(
                'curr' => 'RUB',
                'method' => 'floor',
                'accuracy' => 5,
                'ratio' => array(
                    'all' => 1.1,
                    '001' => 1.2,
                    '0012' => 1.5
                )
            )

            'options' => array(
                'method' => 'floor',
                'accuracy' => 5
            )

            'options' => array(
                'template' => array(
                    array('function' => 'getName'), '!', array('function' => 'getPrice', 'params' => 'EUR'), '!', array('function' => 'getCurrency')
                )
            )
```

So, when I change values in the child object, parent object immediately changes. But when I renew the parent object, children objects looses their references. I tried to reassign the values of parent object(because atomic values sets by values), but it gives nothing:

```
                this.reassignment = function(t, d){
            var that = this;
                $.each(d, function(attr, val){
                    if(typeof(val) === 'object'){
                        that.reassignment(t[attr],d[attr]);
                    }else{
                        if(t[attr] === null){
                            t[attr] = {};
                        }
                        console.log(val);
                        t[attr] = val;
                    }
                });
            };
```

**Question:**
**how can I save references to parent object after reassignment?**

My whole script (kind of library) is too big to post here. Full version http://coding-for-food.com/priceManager/jPanel.js
Page that uses that library http://coding-for-food.com/priceManager/adm.php

Creation of parent object - line 158 (ready method).
Creation of children objects - line 254 (split method).
Problem method - line 648 (reset method).